# SQL - Compare Date in a same Columnn

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a listing for **Ageing Transaction** where areas the list will have 0-30 days column and 31-60 days column.

If transaction date is within 30 days, then its in 0-30 days column, if it's within the range of 31-60 then it's inside 31-60 days column.

So to make it more clear, here's the table

```
|trans_code  |customer    |trans_date | credit|  debit |
|ABC1000     |John ptd    |2014-05-20 |  0.00 | 200.00 |
|ABC1000     |John ptd    |2014-07-06 |200.00 |   0.00 |
|ABC1001     |Petron      |2014-04-25 |  0.00 | 600.00 |
|ABC1001     |Petron      |2014-06-10 |600.00 |   0.00 |
```

John ptd has a debt of $200 on 2014-05-20 and he paid his debt on 2014-07-06. So the date range is within 31-60 days. The $200 he paid will goes into 31-60 days column in Ageing Transaction listing(like below).

```
|Customer    | 0-30 days | 31-60 days|
|John ptd    |     0.00  |     200.00|
|Petron      |     0.00  |     600.00|
```

Now my problem is how to compare trans_date since it's in the same column using SQL. It should be BASED on **trans_code**.

Updated: It's actually starts with Debit before Credit

Comment: What you mean by " differentiate trans_date"? Can you elaborate it?

Comment: Date of Debit is compared with Date of Credit. Then you have the number of days.

Comment: I dont understand. Are you trying to make a report to SHOW the 0-30 column ect? or do you HAVE the 0-30 day column and you're trying to make calculations on it?

Comment: to SHOW the 0-30 column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better approach:

```
SELECT
  d.customer,
  CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(c.trans_date, d.trans_date) <= 30 THEN d.debit ELSE 0.0 END AS `0-30`,
  CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(c.trans_date, d.trans_date) > 30 AND DATEDIFF(c.trans_date, d.trans_date) <= 60 
       THEN d.debit ELSE 0.0 END AS `31-60`
FROM table AS d
INNER JOIN table AS c ON c.trans_code = d.trans_code and c.customer = d.customer
WHERE d.credit = 0.0 and c.debit = 0.0
```

Comment: Good approach. But when I tried with 45 different days (Credit Date - Debit Date), it still went inside 0-30 days.

Comment: The updated code is good, but it when it's 45 days different, it didn't went into 31-60 days. It went into 0-30 days

Comment: perhaps you have more than one pair of debit/credit transactions per each trans_code. If it is the case, the query needs to be modifed. Can you update your answer and include the raw data of the transactions that do not show the correct results

Comment: I see, you start with transaction date of Credit then transaction date of Debit. That's why it went inside 0-30 days not 31-60 days.

Transaction actually starts with Debit where the customer has start his debt, then end with Credit after he paid his debt.

Comment: have a look at the data you have provided . I noticed that as well, but thought that perhaps you look at the transactions from the buyers perspective. I've updated the answer

Comment: Haaa... I've updated my question. Now it's start with Debit then Credit. Sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  t.customer,
  SUM(c1.credit) AS `0-30`,
  SUM(c2.credit) AS `31-60`, 
FROM table AS t
LEFT JOIN table AS c1 ON c1.debit = t.credit AND DATEDIFF(t.trans_date, c1.trans_date) <= 30
LEFT JOIN table AS c2 ON c2.debit = c2.credit AND DATEDIFF(t.trans_date, c2.trans_date) > 30 DATEDIFF(t.trans_date, c2.trans_date) <= 60
```

Take a look at the [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function. You JOIN to the transactions paid within 30 days and to the ones paid within 31-60 days.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).It will look like

```
SELECT trans_code ,customer, GROUP_CONCAT(trans_date), credit, debit, 0-30 days
, 31-60 days 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.customer = table2.customer 
WHERE customer = "John ptd" GROUP BY trans_code
```

Not TESTED.

Comment: 0-30 days and 31-60 days is in Ageing Transaction listing. Not in the database table. Sorry that I didn't make it clear in my question